# Why does mvn install installs project but also removes another (Swagger)?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, maven, swagger

I got a few ressources from the Amazon selling Partner Api (SellersApi,ListingsApi and ProductTypeDefinitionsApi). I tryed installing them to my local repository, but whenever I do "mvn install" in the directory of the SellersApi or the ProductTypeDefininitonsApi it removes the other and I'm not abel to referce it anymore in my IDE. Does anyone have a clue whats happening there and how I may solve this?

pom.xml of ProductDefinitions

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-java-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>swagger-java-client</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
<description>Swagger Java</description>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
</scm>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Unlicense</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Swagger</name>
        <email>apiteam@swagger.io</email>
        <organization>Swagger</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://swagger.io</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-maven</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>2.2.0</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>loggerPath</name>
                        <value>conf/log4j.properties</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- attach test jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add_sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>
                            src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add_test_sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>
                            src/test/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
<groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
        <version>${gson-fire-version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${threetenbp-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.sellingpartnerapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>sellingpartnerapi-aa-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <gson-fire-version>1.8.0</gson-fire-version>
    <swagger-core-version>1.5.18</swagger-core-version>
    <okhttp-version>2.7.5</okhttp-version>
    <gson-version>2.8.1</gson-version>
        <threetenbp-version>1.3.5</threetenbp-version>
    <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
    <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

pom.xml of Sellers

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-java-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>swagger-java-client</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
<description>Swagger Java</description>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
</scm>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Unlicense</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Swagger</name>
        <email>apiteam@swagger.io</email>
        <organization>Swagger</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://swagger.io</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-maven</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>2.2.0</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>loggerPath</name>
                        <value>conf/log4j.properties</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- attach test jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add_sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>
                            src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add_test_sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>
                            src/test/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
        <version>${gson-fire-version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${threetenbp-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.sellingpartnerapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>sellingpartnerapi-aa-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <gson-fire-version>1.8.0</gson-fire-version>
    <swagger-core-version>1.5.18</swagger-core-version>
    <okhttp-version>2.7.5</okhttp-version>
    <gson-version>2.8.1</gson-version>
        <threetenbp-version>1.3.5</threetenbp-version>
    <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
    <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: We need context.  Can you post the maven POM file here, and anything else you use for your maven setup?

Comment: Added the both pom.xml files.